# Cannot overload make_uint4 function

Tags: cuda, overloading, nvcc

I'm trying to overload `make_uint4` in the following manner:

```
namespace A {
  namespace B {
    inline __host__ __device__ uint4 make_uint4(uint2 a, uint2 b) {                                                                                                         
      return make_uint4(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);                                                                                                                              
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to compile it, nvcc returns an error:

```
error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "unsigned int" to "uint2"
error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "unsigned int" to "uint2"
error: too many arguments in function call
```

All these errors point to the `"return…"` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a partial repro on VS 2010 and CUDA 4.0 (the compiler built the code OK but Intellisense flagged the error you are seeing). Try the following:

```
#include "vector_functions.h"

inline __host__ __device__ uint4 make_uint4(uint2 a, uint2 b)    
{        
    return ::make_uint4(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
}
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't include the "::" in the call to return ::make_uint4(). This forces the compiler to use the function in the global namespace not the one you just defined. I think this is part of the issue. Sorry it's hard for me to verify this because I'm using a different setup.

Comment: Yep, that helps. Seems like nvcc is broken here.

Comment: Are you certain nvcc is broken and not that you are in your custom namespace? (check the "Update" in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem compiling it in Visual Studio+nvcc. What compiler are you using?

If that would be of any help: `make_uint4` is defined in vector_functions.h, line 170 as

```
static __inline__ __host__ __device__ uint4 make_uint4(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z, unsigned int w)
{
  uint4 t; t.x = x; t.y = y; t.z = z; t.w = w; return t;
}
```

---

**Update:**
I get similar error when I try to overload the function while being inside my custom namespace. Are you certain you are not inside one? If so, try putting `::` in front of function call to refer to global scope, i.e:

```
return ::make_uint4(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
```

Comment: g++ 4.4.5 + nvcc release 3.2, V0.2.1221

Comment: I don't know the reason then. nvcc 3.2 has no problems neither gcc 4.1.2. btw. check the "update", maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the library code, but it seems like the compiler doesn't like overloaded device functions (as they are treated just like really fancy inline macros). What is does is shadow (hide) the old `make_uint4(a,b,c,d)` with your new `make_uint4(va, vb)` and try to call the latter with 4 uint parameters. That doesn't work because there is no conversion from uint to uint2 (as indicated by the first two error messages) and there are 4 instead of 2 arguments (the last error message).

Use a slightly different function name like `make_uint4_from_uint2s` and you'll be fine.